# Javascript error: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

Tags: javascript

The javascript I am using:

```
javascript: c = '{unit}, ({coords}) {player} |{distance}| {return}';
p = ['Scout', 'LC', 'HC', 'Axe', 'Sword', 'Ram', '***Noble***'];

function V() {
    return 1;
}
window.onerror = V;

function Z() {
    d = (window.frames.length > 0) ? window.main.document : document;
    aid = d.getElementById('editInput').parentNode.innerHTML.match(/id\=(\d+)/)[1];

    function J(e) {
        vv = e.match(/\d+\|\d+/g);
        return (vv ? vv[vv.length - 1].match(/((\d+)\|(\d+))/) : null);
    }
    function K(e) {
        f = parseInt(e, 10);
        return (f > 9 ? f : '0' + f);
    }
    function L(g, e) {
        return g.getElementsByTagName(e);
    }
    function N(g) {
        return g.innerHTML;
    }
    function M(g) {
        return N(L(g, 'a')[0]);
    }
    function O() {
        return k.insertRow(E++);
    }
    function W(f) {
        return B.insertCell(f);
    }
    function P(g, e) {
        g.innerHTML = e;
        return g;
    }
    function X(e) {
        C = B.appendChild(d.createElement('th'));
        return P(C, e);
    }
    function Y(f) {
        return K(f / U) + ':' + K(f % (U) / T) + ':' + K(f % T);
    }
    U = 3600;
    T = 60;
    R = 'table';
    S = 'width';
    s = L(document, R);
    for (j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
        s[j].removeAttribute(S);
        if (s[j].className == 'main') {
            s = L(L(s[j], 'tbody')[0], R);
            break;
        }
    }
    D = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
        s[j].removeAttribute(S);
        if (s[j].className = 'vis') {
            k = s[j];
            if (t = k.rows) {
                D = t.length;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (E = 0; E < D; E++) {
        l = t[E];
        m = (u = l.cells) ? u.length : 0;
        if (m) {
            u[m - 1].colSpan = 5 - m;
            if (N(u[0]) == 'Arrival:') {
                Q = new Date(N(u[1]).replace(/<.*/i, ''));
            } else {
                if (N(u[0]) == 'Arrival in:') {
                    v = N(u[1]).match(/\d+/ig);
                }
            }
            if (E == 1) {
                G = M(u[2]);
            }
            if (E == 2) {
                w = J(M(u[1]));
            }
            if (E == 4) {
                x = J(M(u[1]));
            }
        }
    }
    y = v[0] * U + v[1] * T + v[2] * 1;
    n = w[2] - x[2];
    o = w[3] - x[3];
    F = Math.sqrt(n * n + o * o);
    H = F.toFixed(2);
    E = D - 2;
    s = L(k, 'input');
    i = s[1];
    h = s[0];
    h.size = T;
    B = O();
    P(W(0), 'Distance:').colSpan = 2;
    P(W(1), H + ' Fields').colSpan = 2;
    B = O();
    X('Unit');
    X('Sent');
    X('Duration');
    X('Name to');
    c = c.replace(/\{coords\}/i, w[1]).replace(/\{distance\}/i, H).replace(/\{player\}/i, G);
    for (j in p) {
        z = Math.round([9.00000000, 10.00000000, 11.00000000, 18.0000000015, 22.00000000, 30.00000000, 35.0000000][j] * T * F);
        A = z - y;
        if (A > 0) {
            I = Y(z);
            B = O();
            P(W(0), p[j]);
            P(W(1), A < T && 'just now' || A < U && Math.floor(A / T) + ' mins ago' || Y(A) + ' ago');
            P(W(2), I);
            C = W(3);
            q = C.appendChild(i.cloneNode(1));
            r = C.appendChild(h.cloneNode(1));
            r.id = 'I' + j;
            r.value = c.replace(/\{duration\}/i, I).replace(/\{sent\}/i, new Date(Q.valueOf() - z * 1000).toLocaleString().replace(/.\d{4}/i, '').replace(/(\w{3})\w*/i, '$1')).replace(/\{return\}/i, new Date(Q.valueOf() + z * 1000).toString().replace(/\w+\s*/i, '').replace(/(\d*:\d*:\d*)(.*)/i, '$1')).replace(/\{unit\}/i, p[j]).replace(/\{attack_id\}/i, aid);
            q.onmousedown = new Function('h.value=d.getElementById(\'I' + j + '\').value;');
        }
    }
}
Z();
```

The error I receive:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

A URL looks like this:

`game.php?village=2100&id=4348754&type=other&screen=info_command`

Comment: the `#editInput`-element probably is not present on the page

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. `editInput` is a typo, and the actual id of that element is different (ids are case-sensitive).
2. You are executing this code while the DOM is not ready. To prevent this, execute the code just before the `</body>` closing tag, or wrap it in an event handler for the `load` event of `window` or the `DOMContentLoaded` event of `document`.

**EDITED** How to wrap your code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    //your code here
};
```

Comment: How do I wrap it in an event handler?

Comment: Thanks for editting the post Oscar, sadly this redirects to me a 404 page, or in general it doesn't "inject" any HTML. I am asuming that editInput is a typo than! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I know this comment is late to the game, but the edited answer has an extra ")" at the end that throws a syntax error. I attempted to edit the final answer.

Comment: @Basper53, you were right. Now it's fixed. Thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot my dear  : )

Comment: can't you use defer?

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a conflict between slider and form validator as they were located on different pages but javascript file would of target both of them simultaneously, so all pages that had no slider would come up with "Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null" error, so I have added to the slider If statement:

```
if(document.getElementById("mainImage")){
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
var linkElement = myImage.parentNode;
```

that solved my problem, try it

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to remove child element from parent:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

removeChildEl() {
   this.renderer.removeChild(parent, child);
}
```

but for some reason parent-element does not exist so I need to check via `if` condition:

```
removeChildEl() {
   if(parent)
      this.renderer.removeChild(parent, child);
}
```

so if the parent exists then remove the child otherwise do nothing.