# Fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

After searching for an answer to this, I could not find anything specific relating to the issue we are trying to resolve.

We have a page located here: https://portfolioboss.co/charts

We have several widgets from Trading View:

https://www.tradingview.com/widget/

When we use the code we are putting this portion of the code in the footer of the page just before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d33t3vvu2t2yu5.cloudfront.net/tv.js"></script>
```

Then we have this section elsewhere in the body.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
new TradingView.widget({
"width": 980,
"height": 610,
"symbol": "FX:SPX500",
"interval": "D",
"timezone": "Etc/UTC",
"theme": "White",
"style": "1",
"locale": "en",
"toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
"allow_symbol_change": true,
"hideideas": true,
"show_popup_button": true,
"popup_width": "1000",
"popup_height": "650",
"no_referral_id": true
});
</script>
```

According to Chart View we have things setup properly. According with how Clickfunnels works, we have the code added properly to the settings area of our page.

When our page loads, all other content has been stripped away, but the chart does indeed load. If you view the source code of the page, you will see there is a bunch of content missing. We tried using `window.onload` as outlined in the post shown below for the in page portion of the code, but this did not fix the issue.

See: [Javascript error: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492485/javascript-error-cannot-read-property-parentnode-of-null)

Does anyone know how we can get the page content to display properly and include the charts as well?

Thank you in advance for any help and code examples you can provide.

Comment: The youtube API is trying to insert something before the first `<script>` tag on the page, but there isn't one.

Comment: @Barmar I removed the YouTube video code, that unfortunately did not fix it. Tried adding new YouTube code and that did not fix either. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @Barmar  or if anyone else has any other suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

We have found a workaround using iframes that will do the trick if anyone else has an issue with this in the future that avoids any troubles with Javascript conflicts between Clickfunnels and Trade View.

1. create blank page in Clickfunnels.
2. add tradeview code as shown in original question.
3. load into page you want the tradeview code displayed on, using iframe to call the blank page vs using Trade View js code and attempting to load it in page.