# How to add append </tr><<tr> after every 10 </td> with help of Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I  made a unlimited table generated through php file_put_contents
and in my table i want to add **`</tr><tr>`** after every **`10 </td>`** with help of Jquery or Javascript

Here is the example to table

```
<TABLE BORDER="1" WIDTH="100%" CLASS="Numbers">
<TR>
    <TD>img1</TD>
    <TD>img2</TD>
    <TD>img3</TD>
    <TD>img4</TD>
    <TD>img5</TD>
    <TD>img6</TD>
    <TD>img7</TD>
    <TD>img8</TD>
    <TD>img9</TD>
    <TD>img10</TD>
                           <==== i want here </TR><TR> , which will automatically add after EVERY 10 </td>
    <TD>img11</TD>
    <TD>img12</TD>
    <TD>img13</TD>
    <TD>img14</TD>
    <TD>img15</TD>
    <TD>img16</TD>
    <TD>img17</TD>
    <TD>img18</TD>
    <TD>img19</TD>
    <TD>img20</TD>
                                <=== i want it auto add </TR><TR> here after every 10 </TD>
    <TD>img21</TD>
    <TD>img22</TD>
    <TD>img23</TD>
    <TD>img24</TD>
    <TD>img25</TD>
    <TD>img26</TD>
```

table... continue

Comment: but, your code already has those `</tr><tr>` ... you can see them in the code you posted

Comment: Sir i just added this manually myself to show you i want </tr><tr> here, otherwise it not there

Comment: That wasn't obvious - I guess you have tried exactly nothing yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create and append `TR` to the table (actually it'll be to the tbody, but never mind, this code makes sure it's correct) for every 10 TD's after the first 10, and move those TD's into the newly created row

```js
const cells = [...document.querySelectorAll('TD')].slice(10);
const target = cells[0].parentNode.parentNode;
while (cells.length) {
  target.appendChild(document.createElement('TR')).append(...cells.splice(0, 10));
}
```

```html
<TABLE BORDER="1" WIDTH="100%" CLASS="Numbers">
<TR>
    <TD>img1</TD>
    <TD>img2</TD>
    <TD>img3</TD>
    <TD>img4</TD>
    <TD>img5</TD>
    <TD>img6</TD>
    <TD>img7</TD>
    <TD>img8</TD>
    <TD>img9</TD>
    <TD>img10</TD>
    <TD>img11</TD>
    <TD>img12</TD>
    <TD>img13</TD>
    <TD>img14</TD>
    <TD>img5</TD>
    <TD>img16</TD>
    <TD>img17</TD>
    <TD>img18</TD>
    <TD>img19</TD>
    <TD>img20</TD>
    <TD>img21</TD>
    <TD>img22</TD>
    <TD>img23</TD>
    <TD>img24</TD>
    <TD>img25</TD>
    <TD>img26</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: it works in jsfiddle ...But when i test it locally on my pc use both browsers FF chrome it won't works, i also upload it to my website hosting server, when i test it through website domain it is also not working there

Comment: @smallbee - `it works` good, then I've shown you how to do it. `it won't works` - I can't see the rest of your code, so, you probably nned to check the browsers *developer* tools console for errors, or, keep in mind that the answer here relies on there being only ONE table in the HTML, any more than that, and the results would be itneresting

Comment: After a lot of google search and when i compile your code on many online compilers, i found this error "JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined on line", So i again search for solution i found this add window.onload = function() { your code ]; and it fixed the problem..! Solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492485

Comment: `compile your code` - my code is javascript, it doesn't compile - but the issue is you were trying to run the code before he HTML was present

Comment: I didn't use any extra code, i use same simple table. it show error i fixed it with above solution, and i also check correct answer on your code. You can go and test your code here: https://js.do/code/jaromandax

Comment: no, I don't need to test my code, it works in the answer

Comment: *parentNode of undefined* - you're running this code too soon, your HTML doesn't exist in the DOM at the point your code is running.   As tagged [tag:jquery] add this code inside a doc.ready for a starter.  If your HTML is being added after the page loads, execute this code after your load the HTML.  You can't change DOM elements before they exist.

Comment: https://js.do/code/jaromandax-fixed-it-for-you

Comment: @smallbee just put `<script>` where due, and (if you don't use `defer`) that's right **before the closing** `</body>` tag.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks but you didn't fix anything for me

Comment: @freedomn-m ... not my question, so, your link means nothing to me

Comment: @JaromandaX my bad - I assumed it was OP that said it didn't fix it for them - not sure why you replied with "didn't fix anything for me" - that was directed at OP given it was their link to "test your code here".

Comment: all good @freedomn-m - not sure why OP expects me to know his "actual code" - clearly OP's issue was loading the code before the BODY of the HTML